# Не правильно работает скрипт в убунте

Tags: python, скрипт, ubuntu

Написал простой скрипт который раскидывает картинки внутри каталога, на подкаталоги.
В винде все нормально, а на сервере не работает, картинки которые должны быть в каталоге 
вида `root/small/kh/kha2.jpg` попадают в `root/kh/kha2.jpg` тем самым затирая оригиналы.
Хочется иметь такую структуру:

```
├─media
│ └ uploads
│   └─kiev
│     ├─03
│     ├─0c
│     ├─0e
│     ├─0s
│     ├─0z
│     ├─11
│     └─small
│         ├─03
│         ├─0c
```

А сейчас:

```
 ├─media
 │ └ uploads
 │   └─kiev

import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import shutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
file_count = 0
err = 0
rootdir = sys.argv[1]
t1 = time.time()
small = ''
if not os.path.exists("%s/small/" % rootdir):
    os.makedirs("%s/small/" % rootdir)
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename[0:6]=='small_':
            small = '/small'            
            filename = filename[6:]         
        else:
            small = ''
            small_file = ''
        folder_name = filename[0:2]
        file_count += 1
        try:
            path = "%s%s/%s" % (rootdir, small,folder_name)
            print path
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        try:
            if len(small):
                os.rename(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,"small_%s" % filename)), "%s/%s" %(path, filename))
            else:
                os.rename(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,filename)), "%s/%s" %(path,filename))
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            err = err + 1

print "Total count: %s, time: %s" % (file_count, time.time()-t1)
```

Comment: Проверь filename.
Скорее всего здесь if len(small): оно уходит по второй ветке, потому что small пустая.

Comment: если small пустая, то он и должен по второй уйти, всё верно тут.

Comment: А ты подумай, что если это: if filename[0:6]=='small_': срабатывает неправильно? Тогда small становится пустой, и скрипт на том ифе идёт по второй ветке. И происходит именно то, на что ты жалуешься. Проверь filename.

Comment: как оно может неправильно сработать? Если файл начинается с small_, то и пойдёт по этой ветке.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы и коментарии, но почему скрипт нормально работает в windows?

Comment: хм.. может в венде он проходит сначала по подпапкам, а потом выходит на верхнюю? хотя нет, проверил, он сначала раскидывает всё из верхней, а потом заходит в small и раскидывает оттуда картинки, в имени которых уже нет small. в любом случае вам следует или не использовать os.walk(), как я говорил в ответе ниже, или проверять, есть ли в пути директория small и если есть, то не копировать оттуда файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую поставить на сервер `pudb`, в начале скрипта добавить

```
import pudb; pudb.set_trace()
```

и узнать на каком этапе что-то происходит не так

Comment: чем он лучше ipdb?

Comment: не знаю, мне он привычнее для отладки в консоле

Answer (score 0):

os.walk() гуляет по всем подкаталогам. в итоге заходит в /small и перекидывает оттуда картинки в каталоги к "не small".

```
> for root, subFolders, files in os.walk('/tmp/image'):   
>      print root, subFolders, files

> /tmp/image ['small', 'ee', 'ww', 'e.', 'qq'] [] /tmp/image/small
> ['ee', 'ww', 'e.', 'qq'] []
> /tmp/image/small/ee [] []
> /tmp/image/small/ww [] []
> /tmp/image/small/e. [] []
> /tmp/image/small/qq [] []
> /tmp/image/ee [] ['ee.png']
> /tmp/image/ww [] ['ww.png']
> /tmp/image/e. [] ['e.png']
> /tmp/image/qq [] ['qq.png']
```

устанавливай один root, и бери все файлы в директории, думаю ты и без os.walk() отлично справишься.